# How do I render/format custom fields in the Customer Grid - backend Magento 1.6

Tags: magento

can anybody help me with this ? I have added some custom fields to the customer grid in the magento backend admin page which are select fields , but I cant seem to find a way of showing the "label" in the grid as opposed to the "value" I have tried to find the renderer for this page but have had no luck...

They render ok in the customer information page (please see screenshots)

[image: Customer Grid Sreenshot]

[image]

I have found this post which is very helpful but do not know what i need to write to get the label content to dispay ? http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need any renderer for displaying such values. Here is what you should do:

```
$boyGirlOptions = array(
    array('value' => 1, 'label' => 'Boy'),
    array('value' => 2, 'label' => 'Girl'),
); // or you can fetch dynamically
$this->addColumn('boy_or_girl', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('your-module')->__('Boy or Girl'),
    'index'     => 'boy_or_girl',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => $boyGirlOptions,
    'align'     => 'left',
));

$sourceOptions = array(
    array('value' => 1, 'value' => 'Google'),
    array('value' => 2, 'value' => 'Yahoo'),
    //... 
); //or you can fetch dynamically
$this->addColumn('where_did', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('your-module')->__('Where Did?'),
    'index'     => 'where_did',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => $sourceOptions,
    'align'     => 'left',
));
```

Yes, you need to use dropdown type options and grid values will automatically get the label instead of value(id).
Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks for this excellent answer have got it sorted now ! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You should add `options` parameter to your `$this->addColumn()` statement:

```
    $this->addColumn('column_name', array(
        ...
        'options' => array('id1' => 'label1', 'id2' => 'label2', ...)
    ));
```

Comment: thanks, I have dded this to my statemnet 'options'  => array('1'=> 'Boy','2'=> 'Girl'),

Comment: i have added this to my statement 'options'  => array('1'=> 'Boy','2'=> 'Girl'), 1 - 2 being the values but still does not render in the grid any ideas ? thanks

Comment: You missed `'type'      => 'options',`, see answer above for more info.