# Magento Collection/Grid - Rename field/column values

Tags: php, magento, collections

I'm creating a shipping box report which will allow the admin to see how many of each box is needed to ship the day's orders.  I've already got it saving the internal box codes for each shipment.  The problem is that these codes are things like "SPECIAL_PKG" or "SHIPPING_PKG_1", but the admin should see the human-friendly names instead.

The results are gathered using a typical Mysql4 collection and are shown in a Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid.  Everything works correctly, except that I'm seeing the internal codes instead of the friendly names.

**Is there a way I can rename the codes in the collection results before they are shown?**  For example, if I can obtain an array like this..

```
array(
    'SPECIAL_PKG' => 'Custom Packaging',
    'SHIPPING_PKG_1' => 'Large Box'
)
```

.. then can I use this to somehow change the values displayed on the report?

Unfortunately I can't do a SQL `JOIN` to get these human-friendly names because the data doesn't exist in a single, standardized table.  If I could, I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  I needed to implement a custom renderer by extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract`.  Used [this article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/) as a guide, and it works great!

In case it helps anyone with a similar problem:  I used the constructor to create the array (as shown in my question above).  Then, inside of `render()`, I check if the key exists and show the human-friendly data instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way, your question is exact duplicate of this one: [How do I render/format custom fields in the Customer Grid - backend Magento 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969836/how-do-i-render-format-custom-fields-in-the-customer-grid-backend-magento-1-6)